# TiKz and tikz-grph background of Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, tikz-graphs

the following code turns out well

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-.75,xscale=1]
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]
        \Vertex[L=$1$]{1}
        \SOEA[L=$2$](1){2}
        \SOEA[L=$3$](2){3}

        \SOWE[L=$0$](3){14}
        \SOEA[L=$4$](3){24}

        \SOWE[L=$3$](24){15}
        \SOEA[L=$5$](24){25}

        \SOWE[L=$2$](15){16}
        \SOEA[L=$4$](15){26}

        \SOWE[L=$1$](16){17}
        \SOEA[L=$3$](16){27}

        \SOWE[L=$2$](27){18}
        \SOEA[L=$0$](27){28}

        \SOEA[L=$3$](18){19}
        \SOEA[L=$4$](19){110}
        \SOEA[L=$5$](110){111}

        \Edges(1,2,3,24,25,26,27,28,19,110,111)
        \Edges(3,14,15,24)
        \Edges(26,15,16,27)
        \Edges(19,18,17,16,27,18)

        \draw[rounded corners=1em,line width=1.5em,black,opacity=0.2,cap=round]
        (1.center) -- (2.center) -- (3.center) -- (24.center) -- (25.center) (3.center) -- (14.center);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Like so:

[image: have]

Now I would like to add some more backgrounds: I tried to depict that with... Paint:

[image: desired]

It shall look like the grey background grew further to 3 and then 4. I'd like to have it the same color and same style (with rounding aso.) like the "initial" one, except that it has a small rounded gap. Hope my mouse-drawing skills suffice to make my desire clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure that your code compiles without errors. The first node is called `l` instead of `1`, which causes errors later on. It also always nice if you make examples into complete documents so that it can be copy-pasted into an editor and compiled without any modification.

Comment: there you go. any solutions?

Comment: Was more a general comment, but I did think of one possible approach, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a brute force approach. I draw the shading in the same way as you have done already, then draw a white ellipse over the lower left vertex to simulate the line ending. For the lower of the two new segments I drew a line instead of a circle, to get an even gap all the way.

I also set the `VertexStyle` explicitly instead of using `\GraphInit[vstyle=Empty]` to remove the white fill that is used by default.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      yscale=-.75, 
      VertexStyle/.style={} % removes white fill from vertices
    ]

        \Vertex[L=$1$]{1}
        \SOEA[L=$2$](1){2}
        \SOEA[L=$3$](2){3}

        \SOWE[L=$0$](3){14}
        \SOEA[L=$4$](3){24}

        \SOWE[L=$3$](24){15}
        \SOEA[L=$5$](24){25}

        \SOWE[L=$2$](15){16}
        \SOEA[L=$4$](15){26}

        \SOWE[L=$1$](16){17}
        \SOEA[L=$3$](16){27}

        \SOWE[L=$2$](27){18}
        \SOEA[L=$0$](27){28}

        \SOEA[L=$3$](18){19}
        \SOEA[L=$4$](19){110}
        \SOEA[L=$5$](110){111}

        \Edges(1,2,3,24,25,26,27,28,19,110,111)
        \Edges(3,14,15,24)
        \Edges(26,15,16,27)
        \Edges(19,18,17,16,27,18)

    \begin{scope}[
       on background layer, % everything in the environment is drawn behind the vertices
       highlight/.style={rounded corners=1em,line width=1.5em,black,opacity=0.2,cap=round} % same settings you had, in a style for easier reuse
     ]

        \draw [highlight] (15.center) -- (26.center); % draw top shading
        \fill [white] (15.center) circle[x radius=1.em,y radius=1.em/0.75]; % draw white circle on top of the lower left vertex
        \draw [highlight] (15.center) -- (14.center); % repeat for next segment
        \draw [white,cap=round,line width=2em] (14.center) -- (3.center); % 
 %       \fill [white] (14.center) circle[x radius=1.1em,y radius=1.33*1.1em];
        \draw[highlight] % what you had
        (1.center) -- (2.center) -- (3.center) -- (24.center) -- (25.center) (3.center) -- (14.center);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats already pretty close to what I'd like to have. Thanks. But is it possible to get the gap evenly spaced? I really would like to stick to the `yscale=-.75` but even with `yscale=-1` the spacing next to 0 doesnt look that good.

Comment: @zivimo Better?

Comment: Thats perfect !