# TiKz and tikz-grph - filling and outline non-overlapping

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs, fill, line

I have this code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{external,backgrounds}
%\expandafter\tikzexternalize[]


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        yscale=.75, 
        VertexStyle/.style={} % removes white fill from vertices
    ]
        \Vertex[L=$1$]{1}
        \NOEA[L=$2$](1){2}
        \NOEA[L=$3$](2){3}
        \NOEA[L=$4$](3){4}
        \NOEA[L=$5$](4){5}

        \SOEA[L=$2$](1){22}
        \NOEA[L=$3$](22){23}
        \NOEA[L=$4$](23){24}
        \NOEA[L=$5$](24){25}
        \NOEA[L=$6$](25){26}

        \SOEA[L=$3$](22){33}
        \NOEA[L=$4$](33){34}
        \NOEA[L=$5$](34){35}
        \NOEA[L=$6$](35){36}
        \NOEA[L=$7$](36){37}

        \Edges(1,2,3,4,5)
        \Edges(22,23,24,25,26)
        \Edges(33,34,35,36,37)
        \Edges(1,22,33)
        \Edges(2,23,34)
        \Edges(3,24,35)
        \Edges(4,25,36)
        \Edges(5,26,37)

        \begin{scope}[
            on background layer, % everything in the environment is drawn behind the vertices
            highlight/.style={rounded corners=1em,line width=1.5em,black,opacity=0.2,cap=round},
            whiten/.style={white,cap=round,line width=2em},
            highlightfill/.style={fill,line width=1.5em,rounded corners=1em,black,opacity=0.2,cap=round}
            ]
            % order is important !!!
            \draw [highlightfill] (2.center) -- (4.center) -- (25.center) -- (26.center) -- (37.center) -- (33.center) -- (1.center) -- (2.center);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

producing the following:

[image]

Is it possible to have the outline and filling non-overlapping? Or extend the filling in a manner that its outer shape comes close to the depicted one?

PS: You could also have a look at [TiKz and tikz-grph background of Graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/322189/tikz-and-tikz-grph-background-of-graph/322234?noredirect=1#comment788020_322234).

Comment: If you don't actually need transparency you can just use `black!20` in place of `black,opacity=0.2`. The fill and outline will still overlap, but you won't be able to see one through the other.

Comment: Ahh! Actualy no. Since I already put everything in background. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses an idea from an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29991/is-there-a-way-to-draw-tikz-lines-on-the-inside-or-outside-of-a-path) to clip the stroked path to only show the part outside the path itself. Unfortunately, depending on your viewer [there may still be a slight overlap or gap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220720/clip-in-tikz-leaves-a-faint-outline-of-clip-region-even-after-filling-with-white).

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(-100cm,100cm) rectangle (100cm,-100cm)}}}
\newcommand{\drawoutside}[2][]{
    \begin{scope}[#1, even odd rule]
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
            \clip[reverseclip] #2;
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
        \path[draw, fill=none] #2;
    \end{scope}
    \path [#1, draw=none] #2;
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      every node/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt},
      highlightfill/.style={fill,rounded corners=1em, line width=1.5em,opacity=0.2,cap=round},
    ]
        \path (0,0) node[label=below:a] (a) {}
              (1,1) node[label=above:b] (b) {}
              (0,1) node[label=above:c] (c) {}
              (1,0) node[label=below:d] (d) {};

        \begin{scope}[on background layer]
            \drawoutside[highlightfill, blue]{(a.center) -- (c.center) -- (b.center) -- cycle}
            \drawoutside[highlightfill, red]{(a.center) -- (b.center) -- (d.center) -- cycle}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: no overlap!]

Answer (score 1):

I have just noticed that there is a much simpler solution to the transparency issue: transparency groups. Your original code can actually be used with only a small change.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\usetikzlibrary{external,backgrounds}
%\expandafter\tikzexternalize[]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        yscale=.75,
        VertexStyle/.style={} % removes white fill from vertices
    ]
        \Vertex[L=$1$]{1}
        \NOEA[L=$2$](1){2}
        \NOEA[L=$3$](2){3}
        \NOEA[L=$4$](3){4}
        \NOEA[L=$5$](4){5}

        \SOEA[L=$2$](1){22}
        \NOEA[L=$3$](22){23}
        \NOEA[L=$4$](23){24}
        \NOEA[L=$5$](24){25}
        \NOEA[L=$6$](25){26}

        \SOEA[L=$3$](22){33}
        \NOEA[L=$4$](33){34}
        \NOEA[L=$5$](34){35}
        \NOEA[L=$6$](35){36}
        \NOEA[L=$7$](36){37}

        \Edges(1,2,3,4,5)
        \Edges(22,23,24,25,26)
        \Edges(33,34,35,36,37)
        \Edges(1,22,33)
        \Edges(2,23,34)
        \Edges(3,24,35)
        \Edges(4,25,36)
        \Edges(5,26,37)

        \begin{scope}[
            on background layer, % everything in the environment is drawn behind the vertices
            highlight/.style={rounded corners=1em,line width=1.5em,black,cap=round},
            whiten/.style={white,cap=round,line width=2em},
            highlightfill/.style={fill,line width=1.5em,rounded corners=1em,black,cap=round}
            ]
            % order is important !!!
            \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.2]
            \draw [highlightfill] (2.center) -- (4.center) -- (25.center) -- (26.center) -- (37.center) -- (33.center) -- (1.center) -- (2.center);
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]